# How to detach IMFMediaSession / IMFTopologyNode from hwndVideo?

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

- Reference [How to Play Media Files with Media Foundation](http://Reference%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/player-cpp).
- My main thread has a parent window. I created an EVR child window in the worker thread through MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(HWND hwndVideo, IMFActivate** ppActivate) as a video player. But now the problem is that when the parent window exits, the child window will receive the WM_DESTROY message, which triggers the CloseSession, and the player has WaitForSingleObject waiting for the close confirmation, there may be **a few seconds of stuck**.
- So I look forward to a safe method of Detach hwndVideo. so after that, the worker thread does not depend on the window system and does not affect the main thread.
- But the IMFTopologyNode or IMFActivate / IMFMediaSink documents have not reset the interface method of hwndVideo，and I tried using IMFTopology::RemoveNode to remove the MF_TOPOLOGY_OUTPUT_NODE nodes, and it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

You could probably handle `WM_DESTROY` in parent window and hide and detach (`SetParent`) children preventing their immediate destruction. Either way, however, creating windows from worker threads is almost always a bad idea resulting in artifacts as mentioned. If you could change this behavior, it would result in more reliable design.